# PHP Database Dump Script - are there any issues?

Tags: php, mysql, backup, database-backups

I found a PHP function to dump a mySQL database that someone else had written, and then cleaned it up and formatted it a bit. I wanted to know if I could get a critique of it. I have ran it, tested it on a Wordpress blog and the DB completely restores, but wanted to get some other eyes on the code.

Specifically I am looking for feedback on:

- Anything that could corrupt the data - not properly escaping etc
- Violating any best practice / principles
- Security issues
- Anything else you may see as an issue

NOTE: I am **NOT** looking to use mysqldump, I want to completely generate this sql backup from code. I also realize that the filename could be generated randomly, but the SQL file will be uploaded to dropbox as well, and I want to version it under the same name.

Thanks!

**Code:**

```
  // Variables
  $dbHost = 'DBHOST';
  $dbUser = 'DBUSER';
  $dbPassword = 'DBPASSWORD';
  $dbName = 'DBNAME';
  $tables = '*';
  $fileName = 'mydatabase.sql';


  // Logic
    $link = @mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword);
    $db = @mysql_select_db($dbName, $link);

if(!$link || !$db)
 die("Database Error");

//get all of the tables
if($tables == '*') {

$tables = array();
$result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  $tables[] = $row[0];
    }
}

else $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);


// Loop through tables    
foreach($tables as $table) {

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '. $table);
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
    $return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' . $table . ';';
  $createTable = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE ' . $table));
    $return .= "\n\n" . $createTable[1] . ";\n\n";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {

            $return.= 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' VALUES(';

            for($j = 0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) {

        $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
        $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n", $row[$j]);

        if (isset($row[$j])) { 
          $return .= '"' . $row[$j] . '"' ; 
        } 

        else { 
          $return .= '""'; 
        }

        if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { 
          $return .= ','; 
        }
            }
            $return .= ");\n";
        }
    }

    $return .="\n\n\n";

}

// Save the file
$handle = fopen($fileName, 'w+');
fwrite($handle, $return);
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 4):

That script has serious, deal-breaking problems. It will not work for any but the most trivial database.

- NULLs are not supported.
- Character sets are not taken into account.
- Table names are not delimited.
- Only tables are supported -- not views, stored procedures, triggers, functions, etc.
- [`addslashes()` is not character-set safe](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string).
- `mysql_query()` pre-fetches *all* the rows from the table, so if you query a table with millions of rows, you will exceed your PHP memory limit.  Use `mysql_unbuffered_query()` instead.  On second thought, I see you collect all the output in $return so this is moot.
- Your suppression of errors with the `@` operator is bad practice.  Check for errors and fail gracefully with an informative message.

**Your requirement not to use mysqldump is absurd.**

Why make so much work for yourself reinventing the wheel, and still get it so wrong?   Just run mysqldump via [`shellexec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec).

---

See also:

- [Why is my database backup script not working in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341285/why-is-my-database-backup-script-not-working-in-php/3341381#3341381)

Answer (score 2):

Try `mysql` command or `mysqldump` command

Comment: Author doesn't want to use mysqldump, says in the question

Answer (score 1):

Character sets? Perhaps `SET NAMES utf8` would be a good addition.

Also, what happens if the database contains views?

Answer (score 1):

This will not dump stored procedures, functions, views, triggers and so on.

**Edit:** You can dump procedures etc. this way too. Just use i.e. `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;`
to get the list of procedures and then `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` for each procedure. The same thing for functions, views, triggers...

Don't forget `SHOW CREATE DATABASE;` either.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is a very huge database that needs to be dumped, make sure your server (and php max execution memory per script) has enough memory to keep the whole $return in memory, otherwise you better flush to a file once a while, or every line.

Answer (score 0):

create backup DB :

```
<?php

$dbHost = 'DBHOST';
$dbUser = 'DBUSER';
$dbPassword = 'DBPASSWORD';
$dbName = 'DBNAME';
$tables = '*';

backup_tables($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPassword,$tables);

/* backup the db OR just a table */
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$name;", $user, $pass);


    //get all of the tables
    if($tables == '*')
    {
        $tables = array();

        $result = $db->query('SHOW TABLES');

        $tables= $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

    }
    else
    {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
    }

    $return="";

    //cycle through
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {


        $return.= 'DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
        $result=$db->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table);
        $row2 = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

        $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);

        foreach ($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as  $key=>$value) {

            // build query...
           $return .= "INSERT INTO $table (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($value))."`)
            VALUES ('".implode("', '", $value)."');\n\n";

        }

        $return.="\n\n\n";
    }


    //save file
    $handle = fopen('db-backup-'.date('Y-m-d--H-i-s').'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
    fwrite($handle,$return);
    fclose($handle);
}
```