# Why is my database backup script not working in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database-backups

I am using the Database Backup script by David Walsh(http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php) to backup my MYSQL database as a .sql file to my server.

I created a user named backup and gave it all privileges(just to make sure). Then I put the code into a php file and setup a cron job to run the php file.

This is the code:

```
/* backup the db OR just a table */
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{

    $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($name,$link);

    //get all of the tables
    if($tables == '*')
    {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
    }

    //cycle through
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                    $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                    if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                    if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                }
                $return.= ");\n";
            }
        }
        $return.="\n\n\n";
    }

    //save file
    $handle = fopen('../backup/db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
    fwrite($handle,$return);
    fclose($handle);
}

backup_tables('localhost','alupto_backup','pass','*');
```

When the cron job runs, the backup does not work and I receive an email with the error that appears:

> **Warning**: 
>   mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument
>   is not a valid MySQL result resource
>   in
>   **/home5/ideapale/public_html/amatorders_basic/admin/backup.php**
>   on line **18**

On line 18 is this code:

> `while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))`

When I run the SQL(SHOW TABLES) in phpMyAdmin, it works fine and shows me a list of all the tables. But for some reason, I am receiving an error when the php file tries to run the SQL.

Why is my database backup script not working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will not work to back up your database as an SQL script, unless your database is just a toy database, the equivalent of a "hello world" script.

That script is appalling.  You should not use it to back up a database.  That script has been posted before: [PHP Database Dump Script - are there any issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101993/php-database-dump-script-are-there-any-issues)

- No error checking after mysql_connect() or mysql_queries().  You probably just gave a wrong password or something, but you'd never know because the script doesn't verify the connect was successful.
- It won't produce the right INSERT statement if your database contains any NULLs.
- Character sets are not handled.
- addslashes() is [not suitable](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) for escaping data.
- Table names are not delimited.
- Does not back up views, procedures, functions, or triggers.
- mysql_query() buffers results, so if you have a table with thousands of rows or more, you'll exceed your PHP memory limit.  In fact, the script concatenates the series of INSERT statements into a single PHP variable.  So before it finishes, you will have your *entire* database represented in memory.

**No one should ever use that script.**  It's utter garbage, and I do not say that lightly.

<strike>Just use shellexec() to run mysqldump.</strike>

@Álvaro G. Vicario has a good point, there's no need for you to even use PHP for this task.  I was assuming you need to make a backup from a PHP script.  Here's how I would create a backup from a cron script:

Create a shell script, it can be called whatever you want, e.g. mymysqldump.sh.  Here's how I would write it:

```
:
: ${BACKUP_HOST:="localhost"}
: ${BACKUP_DATABASE:="mydatabase"}
: ${BACKUP_DIR:="/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/backups"}
: ${BACKUP_FILE:="${DATABASE}-`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`"}

mysqldump -h ${BACKUP_HOST} ${BACKUP_DATABASE} > ${BACKUP_DIR}/${BACKUP_FILE}
```

Of course customize the values of the variables as needed for your environment.

You may notice that the username and password are *not* in this file.  Please don't put passwords into scripts in plain text so everyone can read them.  Instead, we'll put them in an options file to make it more secure.

Create a special operating system user who is going to run the backup from cron.  Your system may have a special user "mysql" or "_mysql" to run the MySQL Server, but this user may be configured to have no valid home directory.  You need a user that has a home directory.  Let's call it "mybackup".

Under that user's home directory, create a file `.my.cnf` with the following content:

```
[mysqldump]
user = alupto_backup
password = xyzzy
```

Where "alupto_backup" and "xyzzy" are the MySQL username and its password (change these for your environment).  Set the ownership and mode of this file so that only its owner can read it:

```
chown mybackup .my.cnf
chmod 600 .my.cnf
```

Create a bin directory under this user's home and put our shell script into it.

```
mkdir ~mybackup/bin
mv mymysqldump ~mybackup/bin
```

Now you can run the shell script to test it:

```
sh ~mybackup/bin/mymysqldump
```

Now create a cron file for this user:

```
crontab -u mybackup

@daily ~mybackup/bin/mymysqldump
```

That should be it.

Comment: And it uses the deprecated `ereg_replace()` just to add to the list.

Comment: shellexec? Why even use PHP to run a program via cron?

Comment: Ok, I never realized that. Do you know of a good tutorial that shows how to use shellexec() to run mysqldump?

Comment: Will this backup my database as .sql file?

Answer (score 3):

The script looks very weak IMHO. You should consider using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) it it's available in your system.

## Update

The basic command line would be:

```
mysqldump -hYOURHOSTNAME -uYOURUSER -pYOURPASSWORD infocap > dump.sql
```

You can test mysqldump in your local computer and, once you're happy with the results, either create a shell script or add it directly as a cron task.

Comment: That looks like a good option. Do you know of a good tutorial that shows how to do this? The MYSQL documentation isn't that easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_error() function to see what is that MySQL complains about.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that `mysql_query` does not first return a non-stream.  Try this:

```
....

if (false !== ($result = mysql_query('SHOW TALBES')) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $tables[] = $row[0];
    }
} else {
    // see Mchl's point about mysql_error
}
```

Comment: What would I write in the else clause?

Comment: A simple `echo mysql_error()` would be a good start.  It's just to tell what's wrong with the query.  Any debugging statement would suffice, though.