# Backup MySQL database using php (ideally PDO)

Tags: mysql, pdo, backup

I need to schedule a backup of a MySQL databse on a shared host.
The host doesn't allow me to run shell scripts or mysqldump so that's out.

From the reasearch I've done, it looks like a php solution is my only route. I've seen a few attempts at a solution but none seem to be 100% reliable.
The best I've seen are https://github.com/billkarwin/cats-and-dogs and [PDO MySQL backups function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279066/pdo-mysql-backups-function) but even those seem to have problems or were still under development.

Does anyone here know if there a reliable php class (preferrably using using PDO) for backing up a MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a php backup solution, this is awesome!
https://github.com/ifsnop/mysqldump-php