# How to replace some columns' values while doing an SQL dump

Tags: mysql, sql, dump

I need to do regulars SQL dump to save a database, but in the table "users" there is the columns "name" and "firstname" that must be anonymous (by changing the values with random string or else).
I would like to know how could I dump my data and change the values of these columns at the same time?

This is for a MySQL database

Comment: Why don't you copy that table to another temporary table, change the values, then take a dump of the temporary table. By the way, you should've anonymized the data before storing it in your database

Comment: Create views on all your base tables that obfuscate the data which must be changed.  Then dump the views.

Comment: @xQbert, Have you tried dumping a view with `mysqldump`? It dumps the view definition, not the data from the underlying tables.

Comment: *sigh* seemed like a creative way to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with the `mysqldump` tool. It doesn't have any option for transforming the output, it only dumps the data that is in your database. So if you use `mysqldump`, your options are:

- Store anonymized data and dump that data (as suggested by @DroidX86 in a comment above)
- Get really good at `sed` and use it to filter the output of mysqldump. I *am* really good with sed, and I wouldn't try that.

So you may try to dump data without using `mysqldump`, so you have more options for custom transformations on the data.

You can write a script to `SELECT ... FROM MyTable;` which is basically what `mysqldump` does. But if you write your own tool, you can use expressions to anonymize the name and firstname instead of dumping the contents of those columns as-is.

However, coding your own replacement for `mysqldump` is harder than it sounds. Some developers have attempted it and gotten it spectacularly wrong. I've answered questions about it before:

- [Why is my database backup script not working in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341285/why-is-my-database-backup-script-not-working-in-php/3341381#3341381)
- [PHP Database Dump Script - are there any issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101993/php-database-dump-script-are-there-any-issues/3102200#3102200)